# What is the correct usage of DataContext.Refresh()?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LinqToSql object in memory, whose field values on the database are expected to change during the lifetime of the object.  So periodically I need to check if everything is still in sync.  I was expecting to be able to do this like so:

```
myDataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, myObj);
```

but unfortunately this seems to have no effect; the values on `myObj` remain the same even when the DB values have changed.  [MSDN documentation on this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.refresh.aspx) is pretty scant.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want your refreshed object's current values to match what's currently in the database you'll need to use `RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues` mode instead.

Comment: Aaaaagggggghhhhh!  I can't believe I missed that!  [blushes deep scarlet]

Comment: It seems it doesn't update the associated collection property which maps to another table. It is updating only the properties which map to the column of the table to which the current Entity points to.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "refresh" your entity with the up-to-date values, then the appropriate [mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.refreshmode.aspx) would be `RefreshMode.KeepChanges` or `RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues`.

`KeepChanges` will leave any locally changed value as is. `OverwriteCurrentValues` will fetch all values from the database.

Beware of `ChangeConflictException`s.