# Dynamic filters in Entity Framework do not filter out entities when reading them right after updating

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, filter, dbcontext

I'm using dynamic filters in Entity Framework. It's `DBModelBuilder.Filter` extension method in `EntityFramework.DynamicFilters`. When I modify entity to be filtered out, then in next request using the same DB context it's still visible when read through navigation collections.

Is this normal behaviour? Is there any way to fix it without changing way of updating and reading data in application?

Below is example console application showing my problem.

It works fine when I use different instances of ProductDbContext for reading products indirectly throught categories or when I read categories directly from the same DB context.

**Entities and Db context:**

```
public enum Status
{
    New = 0,
    Used = 1
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id = {Id}, Name = {Name}, Status = {Status.ToString()}";
    }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Filter("OnlyNewProducts", (Product p) => p.Status == Status.New);
    }
}
```

**Categories:**

```
-------------------
| Id | Name       |
-------------------
| 3  | Category 1 |
-------------------
```

**Products:**

```
----------------------------------------
| Id | Name      | Status | CategoryId |
----------------------------------------
| 3  | Product 1 | 0      | 3          |
----------------------------------------
```

**Class showing my problem:**

```
class Program
{
    static ProductDbContext ctx = new ProductDbContext();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Read();
        Modify();
        Read();
    }

    private static void Modify()
    {
        var product = ctx.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Product 1");
        product.Status = Status.Used;
        ctx.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    private static void Read()
    {
        var newProducts = ctx.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Category 1").Products.ToList();

        foreach (var newProduct in newProducts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newProduct.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Id = 3, Name = Product 1, Status = New 
Id = 3, Name = Product 1, Status = Used
```

Updated entity with "used" status should not be shown.

Comment: I found workaround by calling `((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, product)` after saving changes, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

At first, it's not necessary to do this :

```
ctx.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

EF automatically tag the entity as Modified in this case (Come from context, so its a proxy objet).

After many test, I reproduce your behavior. It's not from EF but from dynamic filter. 
The only way I have found is to recreate the context.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Read();
    Modify();
    ctx = new Product2DbContext();
    Read();
}
```

It's not pretty, I know. 
You can add issue here : https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/issues

Other edit: 
After investigation, dynamic filter use Interceptor for rewriting de SQL Request directly. 
When you load your product in the categorie at the first time, interceptor do it's job because it send a SQL command.
At second time, when you try to access to products, category is already known on your context and there products too. So EF doesn't need to execute the query (LazyLoading behavior). So interceptor is not called.
I don't know if you can force the refresh data, I'm trying without success.

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean. But all I'm using is EF. I do not modify any records with SQL command or any other way outside EF. For me it looks like a bug in EF (if there's no solution for my problem).

Comment: In my opinion, it's not a bug. It's not the target for an ORM. You can create a pattern who contains all your data or only changed. When you querie that data you can check your SQL server and your changed data and merged all for extract what you want. The context life time must be shorten as possible.

Comment: @alcoholisevil Why do you think this is EF bug and not a bug/limitation of the **3rd party** package you are using? EF does not support filters, so I don't see your point.

Comment: @IvanStoev, you're right. It's not EF bug, but I still think it's a bug (or limitation as you suggested). If I want to see updated entities, I can easily disable filters. I can't imagine filtering every read data again when I have global filters defined. In my example application it would be easy, but not in web application with repositories and services using all the same DbContext instance for whole HTTP request.

Comment: Is changed data can be not saved ? If not, why not directly save your context ? I understand what you mean, I have same problem with that. I will try correct this by add a layer between my third party and my EF to encapsulate changed data.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. I'm saving DbContext changes right after entity has been modified and before reading it again.

Comment: Oh ! I'm so sorry :$ I missed your SaveChanges(). I understand your request. I will correct my post as soon as possible.

Comment: @alcoholisevil All I was saying was that it's a problem/bug/limitation of `EntityFramework.DynamicFilters` library. The risks of Open Source Software.

Comment: @Cedric, thanks for answering. Creating new instance of DbContext helps. I mentioned about it in my question and I asked for the way of fixing the problem without doing it, so unfortunately I will not use your solution, but I'm sure it will help other people having the same problem.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a ugly solution. But it's work. I hope you can find a greater usefull solution. Please, post your solution you will choose when done. It will be interesting to see how you correct your problem.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This is how Linq works. I've no experience with Entity.

Kind of like what Cedric posted earlier and the comment made by [alcohol is evil]:

```
private static void Modify()
{
    var product = ctx.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Product 1");
    product.Status = Status.Used;
    ctx.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, product);
    product = ctx.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Product 1");
}
```

I have not used Entity, but this is what works in Linq.

The Refresh (again, in Linq) is overloaded to accept `product` or skip it. I've found that if I skip it, then I have to reload the `product` as shown in the line following it.

I hope that helps.

Comment: jp2code, is Refresh method an extension method for DbContext class? Does it need reference to other library? Anyway, in your example refreshing is not necessary because there's no problem with reading modified products directly from DbContext. Problem is when reading modified Products through navigation property of other class.

Comment: [Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6254220/153923) is a member of the DataContext class. It is overloaded with options. I wasn't sure if it would work, but it might give you ideas on how to get your controls to update.